# Unable to restore snapshots in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I can't restore snapshots in Xcode anymore. When I try I get "The item couldn’t be removed because the file name “DVTSnapshotsTmp” is invalid." and Xcode sits for a while sulking before allowing me to cancel and carry on.

I can't find anything on google - in fact googling on the message returns zero hits!

Being a distrustful soul, I always take external back-ups, so it's not critical.

I've tried deleting derived data and existing snapshots, but even new ones from a 'clean' start still raise this error.

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

I have received the same error yesterday, and, like you have no real idea why.

The best I could come up with is to follow the advice in this post: [Manually recover files from Xcode snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311146/manually-recover-files-from-xcode-snapshot).

Whilst I still couldn't restore the snapshot to another directory (and Xcode cracked it), due to a slew of other errors, I could copy each of the files I had changed into TextMate and then copy them into a backed up version.

Would be interested to know why it's happened in the first place. I've just lost too much of my life trying to recover something which I thought I'd had backed up.

Cheers

Comment: Hi. Have you had any further thoughts? I am still getting it with new projects - ones set up since the error first occurred.

Comment: Sadly, no other thoughts. Thankfully, I haven't had the same problem since. I have also made sure I back up things using Time Machine and github to make sure that I don't lose anything. Sorry I can't be much more help. One other factor which might have made a difference, my iMac died. Hard drive failure not long after the problem above, so perhaps that was  contributing factor?

Answer (score 0):

1. create new dummy snapshots with same project (the current broken
   project)
2. go to your Xcode snapshots folder, now there is two snapshots old
   snapshot (the one that Unable to restore) and a new snapshot
3. swap snapshots name in finder
4. open Xcode and try to restore again

Comment: The problem has gone away with the most recent upgrade of Xcode, but I did try something like this. As the error was internal to Xcode rather than the specific snapshots, it affected each and every snapshot regardless of when and how it was created.